# Get RecyclerView last visible item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

`findLastVisibleItemPosition` returns -1 with the following sequence:

```
onViewCreated() {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter = new Adapter());
    adapter.updateContent(List<Content>); // will call notifyItemRangeChanged
    post(new Runnable() {
        run() {
            layoutManager.getLastVisibleItem(); // == -1 (using runnable or not)
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the children views are not ready yet. Using a tree observer on the `RecyclerView` seems to solve the problem, but what would be the best approach to get the last visible item after setting content to the adapter right after creation?

Comment: Maybe you can try.  recyclerView.scrollToPosition(contentList.size() - 1);

Comment: does postDelayed help? you can also try to get the visibleItems in the onViewStateRestored( ) method.

Comment: did you set the layout manager? `recyclervew.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)`

Comment: @AngelKoh: yes, adding delay (1s) helps.

Comment: @Modge: yes, it's set.