# How to stop the Collapsing ToolBar scroll depends on RecyclerView list count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my app I am using Activity & Fragment.Collapsing ToolBar is in Activity and RecyclerView is in Fragment.

I have attached two images. 
* Before Scrolling
* After Scrolling the items are gone up.So created an **empty space at the Bottom.**

Here I need to stop the collapsing if the recyclerview has visible items at there. If items are more, scroll has to be enabled.How to do this? Please help.
Even I referred the below link. But there is no combination of Activity & Fragment Collapsing ToolBar scrolling.

[How to disable scrolling of NestedScrollView&CollapsingToolbarLayout, for example when there is no more content below?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631168/how-to-disable-scrolling-of-nestedscrollviewcollapsingtoolbarlayout-for-exampl?rq=1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create AppBar layout public in activity and in fragment according to recycle view count set expand like this

```
               int itemCount=adapter.size();
               if(itemCount>4){
                    ((YourActivity)getActivity()).appBarLayout.setExpanded(true,true);
                }else{
                    ((YourActivity)getActivity()).appBarLayout.setExpanded(false,true);
                }
```

`adapter.size()` refers to your recycleview adapter count

Comment: Okay Let me check. and intimate you

Comment: And please let me know what is expandToolBar.From where I need to get that value?