# Coordinatorlayout with WRAP_CONTENT scrolling child and CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

My structure is looking like that:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
 <AppBarLayout>
  <CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
  >
    ...
  </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   <TabLayout/>
 </AppBarLayout>

<ViewPager/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

`ViewPager` wraps it's content each time when the page is changed but never takes height more than an available height (like match_parent). The problem in that when `ViewPager` height is less than the available height the `AppBar` is collapsing until it is not visible and there is a lot of empty space under the wrapped `ViewPager`. How can I implement behaviour when the `ViewPager` is less than content available height do not collapse more than needed?

Comment: Can you provide more info, please? The full layout xml, for example?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404979/dont-collapse-toolbar-when-recyclerview-fits-the-screen/32699543#32699543)?

Comment: @Nainal, this will not work in my case