# How to disable CollapsingToolbar's collapse when scroll has not content?

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using android support design 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1' my problem is that when the scroll has no content in it, the collapsing toolbar still enables the collapse action. I need to remove the collapsing of the view if the scroll has no content in it.

My XML :

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/pawfile_header"
                        android:name="com.lightbulb.pawesome.fragments.PawfileHeaderFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/pawfile_timeline"
                android:name="com.lightbulb.pawesome.user_timeline.PawesomeUserTimelineFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**UDPATE QUESTION:**

I'm done with disabling and enabling the collapsing of the view. I used this line of code in order to disable the collapsing:

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams appbarParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)     collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams();
appbarParams.setScrollFlags(0);
collapsingToolbar.setLayoutParams(p);
```

The problem is that the appbar is force to have the elevation of the scrollflags is set to 0. I tried using appbar.setElevation(0) but it has no effect. how can I remove the elevation from my appbar?

Comment: app:layout_scrollFlags = "none".Will this work?

Comment: how can I do that programatically

Comment: There is a nice comment here https://stackoverflow.com/q/32398500/2506817: "When I use a `NestedScrollView` (with `wrap_content` attribute) as main container and a `TextView` as child, the `AppBarLayout` works properly and does not scroll."

Comment: Please check this answer [custom scrolling view behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774587/9947711)

Comment: Please check this answer [custom scrolling view behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774587/9947711)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

get your appbarlayout reference and set the setScrollFlags.

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams p = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
p.setScrollFlags(0);
toolbar.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: this is helpful! but how can I turn back the collapsing

Comment: update the same refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#setScrollFlags(int)

Comment: oww I cant bring back the collapsing of the view... setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED) but cant enable the collapse

Comment: try this setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
    | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);

Comment: how can remove the elevation form the appbar? when I set the scroll flag to 0, eventually the appbar will show an elevation.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar

Comment: setElevation has no effect

Comment: you can bring back the collapsing view : first get scroll flag before setting it to 0 and when you want collpasing back set initial scroll flag you saved earlier

Comment: This does not work as intended because it removes app:behavior_overlapTop effect.

Comment: How do I prevent the CollapsingToolbarLayout from being expanded when using this? It does work by not causing it to expand/collapse when I scroll in the RecyclerView, but it also force it to be expanded.

Answer (score 3):

Try `appbarParams.setScrollFlags(-1);` and `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)` to remove the elevation.

And if you have recyclerView in the fragment, try `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

[Need to disable expand on CollapsingToolbarLayout for certain fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779123/need-to-disable-expand-on-collapsingtoolbarlayout-for-certain-fragments)

Comment: `setScrollFlags` held the toolbar in and expanded state. `setNestedScrollingEnabled` enables to retain the position. this is the cleanest solution for me.

Comment: Can you explain why appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true) removes the elevation? Because for me it doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

To stop collapse of collapsingtoolbar dont give

`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` in the XML file..You can remove that code

Comment: Bad council. Then it will not collapse even if there is content to scroll.

Answer (score -3):

By "scroll has no content in it", I take it that you mean "there is no fragment". For that, I think you'll have to first change the `<fragment>` to a `<FrameLayout>` , then add the fragment programatically using `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()` , and then check if the fragment is present (i.e. not null) like so:

```
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_name) != null) { 
           // here try RKNP's code to disable the appBar from collapsing 
    }
```