# Scroll range of CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to figure out how to have `CoordinatorLayout` scrolling range to be not screen height. My layout structure is following:

> CoordinatorLayout
>
> -- AppBarLayout
>
> ---- CollapsingToolbarLayout (scrollflags: scroll)
>
> ------ Toolbar (CollapseMode: parallax)
>
> ----- /CollapsingToolbarLayout
>
> -- /AppBarLayout
>
> -- NestedScrollView (Behaviour: appbar_scrolling_view_behavior)
>
> -- /NestedScrollView
>
> / CoordinatorLayout

Even when `NestedScrollView` child height is like 100dp it can be scrolled all the way top when the content should not be scrollable at all.

Is there a way to affect the scroll range of `CoordinatorLayout` that if the child content is scrollable it will scroll and only the range that the height is.

I am also seeing this issue when child is `RecyclerView` and it has e.g. 1 50dp height child -> it should not scroll at all in this case, but when child count gets bigger it should then scroll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior` from below link fixes the issue with `NestedScrollView`

https://github.com/natario1/ConstrainedScrollBehavior/blob/master/ConstrainedScrollBehavior.java

Comment: I don't have `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (just some `LinearLayout` inside 'AppBarLayout' that needs to be scrolled when `RecyclerView` is scrolled), but encountered the issue as well.
This solution helped indeed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as there's a scroll behavior in the layout and collapsingtoolbar has a scroll flag, it always can be scroll.

but you can try this trick to disable the scroll

[How to disable CollapsingToolbar's collapse when scroll has not content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557729/how-to-disable-collapsingtoolbars-collapse-when-scroll-has-not-content)