# Hide TabLayout on Scroll of Content instead of ToolBar

Tags: android, android-support-design

I want to hide TabLayout on scrolling my content. Currently I searched the net but I found samples which hide the Toolbar, but I want to hide TabLayout. So please help me. I tried below code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" 
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the example applications:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contextlogic.wish
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.vine.android

Comment: could you clarify your target: hide both Toolbar and TabLayout or just TabLayout (and leave Toolbar visible)?

Comment: Yes Exactly. I want to hide Tab and leave Toolbar as visible.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this approach. The main idea is to move Toolbar outside the CoordinatorLayout and wrap this view structure with other container layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar_container">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/id_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/id_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: whether the title was in the first version? i.e. it disappeared after these changes?

Comment: Hey Sorry, this works fine. I have to uncomment the line
supportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: Thanks, For helping, But Now I'm stuck on weird position. How can I implement NavigationDrawer with my existing requirement. So first navigation item(fragment1) has tab and second navigation items does not has tab. So please help me on that scenario.

Comment: It's rather difficult to recommend the best solution with no information on the architectural details of your app (interconnection of Navigation Drawer, activities, fragments and adapters). Take a look on this [article](https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/). Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I will look in to that link and if not works, do I have to ask another question?

Comment: I created a sample project. Is there any way to upload that on SO or I have to upload that to dropbox. Sorry I'm new to SO.

Comment: Yes, I think that worthwhile to make this question as a separate post. And you can quote valuable parts of your sample project there

Comment: Thanks. I will make a new question.

Comment: It works even without `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Answer (score 6):

*While doing animation on scroll, **CoordinatorLayout** starts searching all the children views of **AppBarLayout** in a linear manner and it stops animating layouts once it finds a layout with non-scrolling tag.*

Exp1:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
         <layout1 with scrollFlag = "scroll|enterAlways">
         <layout2 with no scrollFlag>
    </AppBarLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>

Only layout1 will have animation
```

Exp2:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
         <layout1 with no scrollFlag>
         <layout2 with scrollFlag = "scroll|enterAlways">
    </AppBarLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>

None of them will have animation
```

Exp3: If none of them have scrollFlag, none of them will have animation

Exp4: If both of them have scrollFlag, both of them will have animation

---

In your case, you'll need to keep toolbar outside the coordinator layout and add tablayout as a child of AppBarLayout with scrollFlags = "scroll|enterAlway"

Answer (score 1):

Hello is you wish to disappear the toolbar and the tabs still view, you must write the next code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And if you want hide the TabLayout use scrollFlags in the block of TabLayout

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Comment: Tony, the OP wants the opposite to what you have provided.

Comment: Yeah only consider my last comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `Toolbar` as top view in the layout and replace it with `View` that will placehold previous `Toolbar` space and will scroll as `TabLayout` does, inside your `AppBarLayout`.

Here is how you need to set your layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/preview_top_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> 
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout...> 
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager...>    
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>    <-!--- Toolbar is direct child of CooridnatorLayout and z-order above all views --!->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh4UzOK6oKw)

Comment: Please Provide proper demo, that what should AppBarLayout contains.

Comment: Please don't look for copy and paste solution. I explained it in the text.