# Collapse Toolbar and hide TabLayout on scroll

Tags: android, android-support-design

I want to collapse Toolbar using CollapsingToolbarLayout and then move TabLayout under the Toolbar. 
Here is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="56dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:background="@color/default_green"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now I have collapsing Toolbar, but I don't know how to scroll off TabLayout under the collapsed Toolbar.
I found this  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33011366/3315714), but in such case Toolbar is not collapsing.

Comment: Checkout the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/61941446/5745574

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you currectly, by saying "scroll off TabLayout under collapsed toolbar" you mean hide the TabLayout under the collapsed toolbar, then you should change to the TabLayout the property `app:layout_scrollFlags` to:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```