# How to hide TabLayout, when ViewPager contains additional non-RecyclerView components

Tags: android, android-layout

I face a problem to hide `TabLayout`, when `ViewPager` contains additional non-`RecylerView` components.

Currently, I have the following layout.

[image]

### Before able to hide TabLayout

The XML file is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/portfolioTabIndicatorColor" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The following components are belong to 1 out of 3 child fragments in `ViewPager`.

1. RecylerView - The one which contains white card(s)
2. LinearLayout Footer - The one which contains "Profit" and "RM-5,936.88"
3. LinearLayout Status bar - The one which contains "Daily profit: RM-172.00"

This child fragment of `ViewPager` looks like (More details can be found at https://gist.github.com/yccheok/da69b317e48af132f54c)

### ViewPager's child fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>
    <LinearLayout /> <!-- Footer -->
    <LinearLayout /> <!-- Status bar -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Currently, only `RecylerView` is scroll-able.

Other components like `Toolbar`, `TabLayout`, `LinearLayout Footer` & `LinearLayout Status Bar` location and size are static.

Now I wish to hide `TabLayout` while scrolling `RecylerView`. I refer to [Hide TabLayout on Scroll of Content instead of ToolBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009127/hide-tablayout-on-scroll-of-content-instead-of-toolbar)

---

### After able to hide TabLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/portfolioTabIndicatorColor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The outcome isn't my desired, as "LinearLayout Footer" and "LinearLayout Status bar" are being pushed down**

[image]

But scroll to hide `TabLayout` some how works. Please refer to the 2 screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible?

1. Continue make LinearLayout footer and LinearLayout Status bar part of ViewPager's child fragment layout.
2. Make location of LinearLayout footer and LinearLayout Status bar static.
3. Able to hide `TabLayout` when perform `RecylerView` scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I want, by following tutorial at

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/

http://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part2%29/

The key ideas are

1. Don't use `CoordinatorLayout`
2. Place `TabLayout` and `RecyclerView` within `FrameLayout`, so that `TabLayout` will overlay on the top of `RecyclerView`
3. Add top padding on `RecyclerView`. Having `android:clipToPadding="false"` is important as well.
4. To hide/ show `TabLayout` during scrolling, attach [HidingScrollListener](https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/michalz/hideonscrollexample/listener/parttwo/HidingScrollListener.java) to `RecyclerView`.

The shortcoming for this solution is that, `requiresFadingEdge` will no longer work on `RecyclerView`, due to the top padding.

Answer (score 0):

in my understanding to achieve this you will have to define the layout in your activity xml rather than fragment inside the view pager. and communicate data from the fragments to the activity using maybe an interface which can change the data of the LinearLayout and StatusBarLayout you can use         `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` for your LinearLayout and StatusBarLayout container to position them statically at the bottom of your coordinator layout.

Answer (score 0):

In the conditions where you are not using the recycle view. Try wrapping the views with a nested scroll view which is available in the support library. This will enable the scrolling behavior for the coordinator layout.