# How to hide viewpager tabs on scrolling listview.?

Tags: android, android-layout

Scenario:  I  have  three  fragments  in  ViewPager.  I  have  one  list  in  one  fragment.

Problem:I  want  to  hide  viewpager tabs and  show  only  toolbar  and list only?

Can  anyone  solve my  problem

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009127/hide-tablayout-on-scroll-of-content-instead-of-toolbar

Comment: How to hide if  I  am  scrolling  list  in  fragment  ?