# How to hide Toolbar and TabLayout

Tags: android, widget, android-tablayout, tabbar

The problem is that ToolBar is hiding, if you swap specifically for it. But if you scroll the contents of the window, the ToolBar remains motionless, but it should be vice versa.
But in general TabLayout should hide, and ToolBar always remain on top.
I do not know how to implement it, help, pls.

P.C. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009127/hide-tablayout-on-scroll-of-content-instead-of-toolbar) topic - it didn't help

My code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"

  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" />


      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/backTabColor"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance"
        />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: app:layout_collapseMode="pin" add this to Toolbar layout

Comment: i was making this, but nothing change

Comment: ToolBar - hidden, when I move him, but if i move content - ToolBar is stay